# How to modify Activity's savedInstanceState so that new data is used to recreate DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment, recreate

I have a `DialogFragment` listing data generated at `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)`. When the `Activity` is recreated on, for example, orientation change, `DialogFragment` is recreated using old data from previous `Activity` instance.

`DialogFragment` is recreated at `Activity`'s `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` using `savedInstanceState`. How to modify `savedInstanceState` so that new data is used to recreate `DialogFragment`?

Answer (score 1):

This probably should work.

In fragment class

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Comment: This only recreates `DialogFragment` using old data from previous `Activity` instance. When the `Activity` is being recreated, new data is generated at `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)`. `DialogFragment` should be recreated using those new data.

Comment: So you are having different data in activity every time orientation changes? And you want to pass it to dialog fragment every time?

Comment: Yes. Data may be different in each activity recreation.

Comment: So why you are using data from savedInstanceState to recreate dialogFragment then you already have new data?

Comment: I didn't override `onCreate`/`onSaveInstanceState` in `DialogFragment`. It is automatically recreated when calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in the `Activity`. I can stop the recreation by calling `super.onCreate(null)`, but it is an overkill.

Comment: Try to detach and attach your fragment.

Comment: I find out it is not necessary to detach and attach the `DialogFragment` to recreate the `Views`, as `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateDialog` is called after `Activity`'s `onCreate`. The problem is at `DialogFragment`'s `onActivityCreated`, which recovers saved `Dialog` state even when new data is applied. Override `onActivityCreated` to call `super.onActivityCreated(null)` solves the problem.